# How do I get the attributes of an object in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to Ruby and Rails. I've been trying to get a view of all users to work and am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have a view with:

```
<% provide(:title, "View all Users") %>

<h1>Users#viewall</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/viewall.html.erb</p>

<% 
@users = User.all 
@users.each do |user|
  user.name
end
%>
```

The output of this is a list of objects in the database, with all the object's data. When I want to target (for example) just the name, it doesn't work.

```
[#<User id: 1, name: "user name", email: "mail@mail.com", created_at: "2016-08-03 15:40:41", updated_at: "2016-08-03 15:40:41", password_digest: "$2a$10$KmWWK86H/dj.HAp9zcHOUOCbph1rawIer41kyH4dIrV...">]
```

What am I missing here? I'm not even really sure what to google as I don't know what the loop is spitting out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to output the information. So in ERB when you have a tag like:

```
<% i = 4 %>
```

That executes code. When you have:

```
<%= "hi" %>
```

That outputs the return value. So what you actually want is this:

```
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

What you should do with the users though, is setup an instance variable in your controller:

```
def viewall
  @users = User.all
end
```

Then use it in your view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Just better to keep SQL calls and a lot of logic out of your views. Leverage the controllers, models and helpers to do that.

Comment: Thanks, the extra explanation was really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You are not displaying the data to the user.

In your controller method, is where you should add

```
@users = User.all
```

And in your view

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <h1><%= user.name %></h1>
<% end %>
```

- **<% %>**: These brackets are used to evaluate an expression
- **<%= %>**: These brackets evaluate an expression and render the output